# Async exception not being caught or being swallowed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

**Update from the future:** TL;DR to catch expressions in async methods you have to `await`, `Task.WaitAll`, or `.Result`.

I created a somewhat convoluted async method that just runs other async methods. You can disregard most of it as only the line var mSpekTask... is of interest, also, I don't care about the logic, I only want to know where my exception went. My main problem is that ex.ToString() is never hit even though inside mSpecTask an exception definitly happens.

```cs
public async Task LoadAsync(IEnumerable<ProductRequest> feed, int? customerId,
    IProgress<int> mSpecProgress, Action<Task> mSpecCompletionHandler)
{
    var ids = feed.Select(x => x.ProductId.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();

    try
    {
        var mSpecTask = this.LoadMSpecAsync(mSpecProgress, ids);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here is the code for LoadMSpecAsync

```cs
public Task<ResultSet> LoadMSpecAsync(IProgress<int> prg, IEnumerable<string> ids)
{
    return this.LoadAsync(prg, ids, Selector.M, SPMS, x => x.Order);
}
```

Here is the code for LoadAsync, await db.ExecuteTVP(progress, spName, ids, parameters) generates an exception.

```cs
private async Task<Dictionary<Pair, dynamic>> LoadAsync(IProgress<int> progress,
    IEnumerable<string> ids, Selector s, string spName, Func<dynamic, int> k,
    Func<dynamic, dynamic> f = null, object parameters = null)
{
    parameters = new ExpandoObject().CopyFromSafe(parameters);
    if (spName != SPMAP) ((dynamic)parameters).lang = this.languageCode;

    using (var db = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
    {
    await db.OpenAsync();

    var results = await db.ExecuteTVP(progress, spName, ids, parameters);

    db.Close();
    }

    return this.data[s];
}
```

Comment: If we can disregard most of it, why do you post it in the first place? Please only post the relevant parts. Even better: Create a short, clean reproduction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When an `async` method throws an exception, that exception is placed on the returned `Task`. It's not raised directly to the caller. This is by design.

So, you have to either `await` the `Task` returned from `LoadMSpecAsync` or have your `mSpecCompletionHandler` examine its `Task` argument for exceptions. It will show up there.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle unobserved Task exceptions as follows:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs eventArgs) =>
{
      eventArgs.SetObserved();
      ((AggregateException)eventArgs.Exception).Handle(ex =>
      {
          //TODO: inspect type and handle exception
          return true;
      });
};
```

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea that was possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add an answer to my own question because there's a useful piece of information that I found out. The intermediary method LoadMSpecAsync is swalloing the exception. For this not to happen it needs a little teak. You need to add the async keyword before the return type and the "await" keyword after "return".

Answer (score -2):

I had an Exception being swallowed by *myTask.Wait()* (or WaitAsync), but it was a task-nesting issue.  That is, when I did the *myTask.Wait()*, *myTask* had a *passed-in parameter Task* that ALSO called *myParameterTask.Wait()*.  The *parameter task* had its own **Exception-catch and no *throw***, so the originally thrown Exception wasn't propagating back to the calling thread.

I thought there was an issue with *myTask.Wait()* throwing Exceptions, but it wasn't.